# How to convert List<object> to List<CustomClass>?

Tags: c#, json, linq

I'm building a class library that connects to a client's API, and collects the response from a given endpoint into a class. In other words, I'll hit the client's Donuts endpoint, and using JsonConvert to deserialize the response into my Donuts class, which has fields that match the attributes in the JSON object. This is all well and good, but they have a lot of endpoints, and I have many methods which repeat the same code over and over. In the interests of DRYness and separation of concerns, I'd like to have a separate namespace that makes the rest call, no matter the endpoint, and returns the correct result to the main class. Here's an example of what it does now (I'm using RestSharp to configure the request and response):

```
public List<T> Index<T>(string Endpoint)
    {
        List<T> Results = new List<T>();
        RestClient Client = new RestClient();
        RestRequest Req = ConfigureGetRequest(Endpoint);
        IRestResponse Resp = Client.Execute(Req);

        if (Resp.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(Resp.Content, DeserializationSettings);
        }
        return Results;
    }
}
```

There's other code in the if statement (it's actually an if-else for error handling), but it's not really relevant to this question. I have this same code in multiple methods, with the only difference being that it returns `List<Bagel>`, or `List<Cruller>`, etc... What I'd like to do is extract this code into it's own method, but I'm not sure how. Right now, I'm trying to deserialize into `List<object>`, and then convert it to `List<Donut>` later, but that doesn't seem to be something I can do. My other thought is to pass in the endpoint name as a parameter (`public List<Donut> GetDonuts(string Endpoint)`), and then somehow use that to determine what type of object to deserialize into, if that makes sense? Anyhoo, if anyone has any insight on a good way to do this, it would be appreciated!

EDIT

Awesome responses, thank you folks. I've refactored the method according to Matt Dillard's answer below. The next step is to convert the List to List. The method that calls the method above looks like this:

```
public List<Donut> GetDonuts()
{
    List<Donut> Results = new List<Donut>();
    MODULE MakeCall = new GET();
    return Results = MakeCall.Index("donuts")();
}
```

My Intellisense tells me that "The type arguments for method 'MODULE.Index(string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly". I tried casting like so: (List)MakeCall.Index("donuts")();
but that didn't work out. Is there a way to cast this so that I can have methods GetDonuts, GetCrullers, etc... that all call Index effectively?

Comment: If you have a `List<object>`, that's a code smell. Generics are probably the fix. Then you can do things like `List<Donut> donuts = GetStuff<Donut>(); List<Cake> cakes = GetStuff<Cake>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what needed to happen. I can't deserialize a generic list, but I can deserialize a generic, and place it in a list. The final code looks like this:

```
public List<Donut> GetDonuts<T>()
{
    GET MakeCall = new GET();
    List<Donut> Results = new List<Donut>();
    Results = MakeCall.Index<Donut>();
    return Results;
}

public List<T> Index<T>()
{
    T Result;
    List<T> ResultList = new List<T>();
    RestClient Client = new RestClient();
    RestRequest Req = ConfigureGetRequest(Endpoint);
    IRestResponse Resp = Client.Execute(Req);

    if (Resp.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Resp.Content, DeserializationSettings);
        ResultList.Add(Result);
    }
    return ResultList;
}
```

This allows me to use GetDonuts, GetCrullers, etc... to be lean and DRY. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 6):

Generics:

```
public List<T> GetStuff<T>(string endpoint)
{
        List<T> Results = new List<T>();
        RestClient Client = new RestClient();
        RestRequest Req = ConfigureGetRequest(endpoint);
        IRestResponse Resp = Client.Execute(Req);

        if (Resp.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(Resp.Content, DeserializationSettings);
        }
        return Results;
    }
}
```

Bascially replace all references to `Donut` with `T`.

Presumably the endpoint address would change, so you can add that as a parameter.

Call something like this:

```
var donuts = GetStuff<Donut>("http://dunkin.com/api/allthedonuts");
```

Comment: You'll want to add the <T> to the method as well to allow him to pass the type.

var donuts = GetStuff<Donut>();

Comment: @Cory: Whoops. Missed that.

Answer (score 4):

You probably would like to have it as generic method which accepts a type `T` and return a list of such like

```
public List<T> GetDonuts<T>() where T : class, new()
    {
```